# Получение изображения курсора

Tags: c, windows, winapi, курсор

Можно ли определить реальное изображение курсора на экране, в том случае, если программа использует свое(не системное) изображение. Насколько я понял, курсор существует вне всяких контекстов и получить его изображение средствами winapi не получится. Поэтому лучшие решения состоят в том, чтобы дорисовать его на скрин на основе текущего системного курсора. А все-таки, неужели его нельзя выцепить, в конце концов, существует такая вещь как видеобуфер, которому пофиг на контексты устройств. Заранее спасибо.

Да, все гениальное просто. Зачем гонятся за экраном, когда можно элегантно и просто выдернуть изображение из ресурсов. Огромное сяб за помощь. Выглядит как-то так:

```
CURSORINFO ci;
ICONINFO ii;

ci.cbSize= sizeof(CURSORINFO);      
if(!GetCursorInfo(&ci))
    MessageBox(NULL, "GetCursorInfo", "Oops", MB_ICONERROR);        
hCursor= ci.hCursor;

ii.fIcon= FALSE;
if(!GetIconInfo (hCursor, &ii))
    MessageBox(NULL, "GetIconInfo", "Oops", MB_ICONERROR);  
hBitmap= ii.hbmColor;
```

Comment: Что тут подразумевается под "действительное изображение курсора"? Обычно изображение текущего курсора мыши и его маску можно получить без проблем. Также можно открыть все стандартные курсоры.

Comment: Подправил. Имеется ввиду, когда, (игра например), загружает свое изображение курсора, есть там что-то такое в winapi. И я хочу получить это изображение.

Comment: Если она просто заменяет системный курсор на свой, то никаких сложностей не должно возникнуть, если же отрисовывает сама - тот тут понадобится глубокая обратная разработка.

Comment: Поподробне можно, начиная с никаких сложностей? ). И кстати, как раз если отрисовывает сама, значит в контексте окна\экрана. Это-то как раз вообще не проблема

Comment: Получаете курсор (HCURSOR) средствами WinAPI. А если отрисовыват сама, то его изображение вы просто так не получите.

Comment: И? Что я могу получить с этого дескриптора, кроме координат? Картинку-то как словить?

Comment: Из этого дескриптора можно получить два битмапа - картинку и маску, так же как и с иконки.

Comment: хм.... а вот тут у меня похоже пробел в знаниях, пойду гуглить )

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-geticoninfo

Comment: Отлично, огромное спасибо. дело сдвинулось на лад, я действительно получил изображение курсора, хотя до конца не понял еще как )).